# How to store SharedPreferences into file?

Tags: java, android

I have been developing Android application which should have following function: it should store some data between Application executings; also if I delete application and re-install it app should restore values of data. I knew that I can store data into SharedPreferences (for working with data in my program) and serialize into file in onDestroy() event. But SharedPreferences is Non-Serializable class and I can't use it. Please, suggest me another way for my task, or tell me how I can serialize SharedPreferences. I know that I can just write important data into simple file but may be there is another means for my problem? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to be able to store data locally after you delete an app, except if you put the data on the SD card, but at that point everyone can read/write/delete it.

Check this out for more information on data storage:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would store your settings in an SQLITE db or in some sort of http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Properties.html

Cheers